# Vue.js Vee Validate how to do a validation with in a scope of elements

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I'm using [VeeValidate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/) pluggin for the validation in my project.

**This is my form I'm going to validate.**

[image]

**If I want to validate all fields at the save button**

```
this.$validator.validateAll().then(result => {
    if (result) {

    }
    // alert("Correct them errors!");
}
```

This kind of function would help.

But what if **I want to validate University and course at the add button.**
Instead of validate all is there a way to pass only that two field names (uni and cou) for the validate?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `data-vv-scope` of `vee-validate` to achieve this functionality. Here is how it can be done

```
<input 
      id="university" 
      name="university" type="text"
      v-model="<model_of_university>"
      data-vv-rules="required" 
      data-vv-as="University"
      data-vv-scope="university" required/>

<input 
      id="course" 
      name="course" type="text"
      v-model="<model_of_course>"
      data-vv-rules="required" 
      data-vv-as="Course"
      data-vv-scope="university" required/>
```

Now, in oder to validate these fields just pass the `data-vv-scope` value in the `validateAll` method as following

```
this.$validator.validateAll('university').then((result) => {
 if (result) {

    }
    // alert("Correct them errors!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can tell the validator to scope the fields by adding a data-vv-scope. Those fields will be then identified using their name and their scope. You can have inputs with the same name in different scopes, and you can display, clear and validate those scopes independently.

For convenience, you may add the data-vv-scope attribute on the form that owns the inputs, you don't have to add the attribute on every input. You can also pass scope property to the validator expression.

```
<v-form  data-vv-scope="form1" >
                <v-text-field v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" type="text" name="username" data-vv-scope="form1"/>
                <span>{{ errors.first('form1.username') }}</span>

        </v-form>

        <v-form  data-vv-scope="form2" >
                <v-text-field v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" type="text" name="username" data-vv-scope="form1"/>
                <span>{{ errors.first('form2.username') }}</span>

        </v-form>
```

// click event, will validate the form1

```
  submit() {

        this.$validator.validateAll('form1').then(valid => {

                  if (valid) {


                  }
                   });
      }
```

Please refer to the following link: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/scopes.html

Answer (score 1):

try it , in your code put this:

```
this.$validator.validateAll('nameForm.*').then((result) => {
  enter code hereif (result) {
  // pass
}
// alert("Correct them errors!");
```

}

this would validate all form

Answer (score 0):

To validate only two fields, you can use the attribute data-vv-scope="university" in these inputs, then:

```
this.$validator.validate("university").then((isValid) => {
      if (isValid) {
        ...             
      }
})
```

If you want to validate all fields of all scopes at the same time:

```
this.$validator.validateScopes().then((isValid) => {
      if (isValid) {
        ...             
      }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58976562/edit) to include an explanation for your code, and how it's different from the other solutions on this page. This will increase your answer's usefulness and make it more likely that your solution gets upvoted :)